# In ActiveMQ WebSockets Is there a way to a allow a grace period on Heartbeats?

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

We are using STOMP over WebSockets ([ref](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/)) into ActiveMQ 5.15.

With this we are defining a client (to server) heartbeat of 20 seconds. The notification of this time is built into the STOMP protocol so communicated to the server.

```
CONNECTED server:ActiveMQ/5.15 heart-beat:0,20000 session:ID:app.server.mycompany.com-43039-1617089631808-3:3585 version:1.1
```

The client heartbeat code depends on browser `setInterval()` and this doesn't appear fully reliable so occassionally the heartbeat doesn't get sent and the server then ends up killing the connection.

```
 Transport Connection to: ws://10.x.x.x:50670 failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too (>20000) long:
```

I have noticed that there is a `transport.hbGracePeriodMultiplier` setting on [pure Stomp connector in ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) however the Stomp over WS client connects in on [ActiveMQ WebSocket connector](https://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html).

My question is: is there an equivalent grace period setting for WebSockets?

Comment: I assume you have tried adding this 'transport.hbGracePeriodMultiplier' to the websocket transport configuration?

Comment: @RobNewton - yes - I tried ` <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:30014?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.hbGracePeriodMultiplier=4.0"/>` without any noticeable change in behaviour